# ASP.NET Core 5.0 Bootstrap 5.0 - sidebar

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrapping

I'm trying for like past 6 hours to create static not collapsible sidebar using Bootstrap 5.0, but unfortunately without success.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - ASP.NET</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="sticky-top">
              <!--here will be sidebar-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="container">
                <main role="main" class="pb-3">
                    @RenderBody()
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <div class="sticky-top">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - ASP.NET - <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I have made comment where I want to put it.

I'm fully aware there are a bunch of tutorials and examples online, but they are not using raw Bootstrap 5.0, because even when I copy it 1:1, it returns plenty of warnings about missing classes, and as a result sidebar looks like it was made by someone who learns HTML for last few hours.

Horizontal navbars are fully supported, but creating working vertical sidebar looks impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blazor server template does a decent job at a side navigation bar. It's not the same as asp.net but the css in the template might give you some new ideas of things to try.